AlwaysEncrypt: Error when altering stored procedure
We have encrypted a column using Always Encrypted. Used deterministic encryption. In the sample query  [EncryptedSIN] is the encrypted column in [Customer] table. We understand that deterministic encryption allows equal comparison(=) and following query works as expected. Please note that we are executing these queries in SQL Server Management Studio(20.1)
declare @MatchedSIN varchar(9)=''
declare @SINFilterValue varchar(9)='000000000'
SET @MatchedSIN =(select [SIN] from  [dbo].[Customer] where [EncryptedSIN]=@SINFilterValue)
select @MatchedSIN

If I write the same functionality as a stored procedure, I'm getting error
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Select_Customer]
(                              
  @SINFilterValue varchar(9)                             
) 
AS
BEGIN
 declare @MatchedSIN varchar(9)
 SET @MatchedSIN =(select [SIN] from  [dbo].[Customer] where [EncryptedSIN]=@SINFilterValue)
 select @MatchedSIN
END

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
Must declare the scalar variable "@SINFilterValue".
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal error. Metadata for parameter '@p28f0fcb0efbe49679912c93e9b607b4a' in statement or procedure 'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Select_Customer]
(
@SINFilterValue varchar(9)
)
AS
BEGIN
declare @MatchedSIN varchar(9)= @p28f0fcb0efbe49679912c93e9b607b4a;
SET @MatchedSIN =(select [SIN] from  [dbo].[Customer] where [EncryptedSIN]=@SINFilterValue)
select @MatchedSIN
END
' is missing in resultset returned by sp_describe_parameter_encryption.
Please note that we've selected the option "Enable parameterization for AlwaysEncrypted" from Query Options-> Advanced in Sql Server Management Studio.
Any help will be appreciated.
I'm trying to compare the encrypted column value against a parameter value.
